# Azure Heartbeat Table: _ResourceId is blank

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I recently wrote some logic for alerting on VMs offline outside of their start-stop schedules, based on the `Heartbeat` table.  However, that produced some unexpected results, as the `_ResourceId` value was blank (i.e. empty string; not null) for a number of lines.

i.e. the below query returned 22 rows covering 19 distict VMs, all at different times.

```
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated >  ago(7d) and _ResourceId == ''
| project  _ResourceId, Computer, TimeGenerated
| order by TimeGenerated, Computer
```

Is this a bug, or could there be a legitimate reason for this?

Searching around so far I've found no bug reports for this, or mentions of why this behaviour may be seen.

### Additional Info

Here's the query I'm using to monitor for offline VMs outside of legitimate stop/start actions.

```kusto
let lastHealthyCheckin = ago(5m);
let pollingWindow = ago(7d);
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > pollingWindow
  and ResourceId != '' // this line added to avoid the "bug" mentioned here
| summarize LastCheckIn = max(TimeGenerated) by _ResourceId, Computer
| where _ResourceId !in (
    AzureActivity
    | where OperationNameValue in~ (
        'MICROSOFT.COMPUTE/VIRTUALMACHINES/START/ACTION', 
        'MICROSOFT.COMPUTE/VIRTUALMACHINES/DEALLOCATE/ACTION'
    )
    and TimeGenerated > pollingWindow
    | summarize LastStop  = max(case(OperationNameValue =~ 'MICROSOFT.COMPUTE/VIRTUALMACHINES/DEALLOCATE/ACTION', TimeGenerated, datetime(null))) 
      ,         LastStart = max(case(OperationNameValue =~ 'MICROSOFT.COMPUTE/VIRTUALMACHINES/START/ACTION', TimeGenerated, datetime(null))) 
      by _ResourceId
    | where LastStop > LastStart
    | project _ResourceId
)
| where LastCheckIn < lastHealthyCheckin
| project Computer, _ResourceId, LastCheckIn
```